# Difiere mucho "ng2-webstorage" y "ngx-webstorage"

Tags: angular

Estoy actualizando una aplicación de Angular 2.4 a Angular 9, y tengo la duda de "ng2-webstorage" y "ngx-webstorage" porque la primera esta en desuso y la segunda es la que tendría que usar ahora, pero no encuentro información acerca de como migrar.
Quizá no he buscado bien o no supe como buscar, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ng2-webstorage* y *ngx-webstorage* son la misma libreria, solo que han cambiado de nombre, esto no quiere decir que esté en **desuso**. Simplemente debes actualizar tu versión. Probablemente debas ejecutar en tu proyecto `npm uninstall ng2-webstorage` y posteriormente `npm install ngx-webstorage`.

Según la documentación lo único que debes hacer para **"migrar"** de una versión a otra es cambiar el nombre del módulo.

Espero haber contestado tu pregunta!

Aquí dejo el repo de la libreria.
[Enlace a Github](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información!